# Ressource announcement - Message queing registry on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have an application which makes use of RabbitMQ messages - it sends messages. Other applications can react on these messages but they need to know which messages are available on the system and what they semantically mean.

My message queuing system is RabbitMQ and RabbitMQ as well as the applications are hosted and administered using Kubernetes.

I am aware of

- https://kubemq.io/: That seems to be an alternative to RabbitMQ?
- https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/event-registry/ also an alternative to RabbitMQ? but with a meta-layer approach to integrate existing event sources? The documentation is not clear for me.

Is there a general-purpose "MQ-interface service availabe, a solution, where I can register which messages are sent by an application, how the payload is technically and semantically set up, which serialization format is used and under what circumstances errors will be sent?

Can I do this in Kubernetes YAML-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not have this in any kind of generic fashion so you would have to write it yourself. Rabbit messages are just a series of bytes, there is no schema registry.